# How to extract the variable name by using BeautifulSoup

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

`<td class="right" data-stat="players_used">23</td>`
Trying to extract the string "players_used" through BeautifulSoup.

Currently, I am able to extract the content from this tag but I have no idea how to extract the string "players_used" through BeautifulSoup. Can someone have a look at this?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `.get()` to extract the attributes value:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<td class="right" data-stat="players_used">23</td>')

soup.find('td').get('data-stat')
```